# How to copy mongo db from mongodb 3.0 to mongodb 3.6 on ec2 bitnami image

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mongodb, bitnami

As the title implies, I need to copy db from `ec2` instance with `bitnami` image that has `mongodb` pre-installed with version 3.0.9 , to new `bitnami` `ec2` instance that has `mongodb` version 3.6.8 pre-installed.

I first used:

```
db.copyDatabase("my_db", "my_db", "000.00.00.000", "root", "xxxxxxxxxx")
```

but then I received the following output:

```
{
"ok" : 0,
"errmsg" : "Server min and max wire version are incompatible (0,3) with client min wire version (6,6)"
}
```

Now, from what I understand, This messages is implying that `mongo` cannot copy the db since they are 2 different `mongo` versions.

So from the 2 cent knowledge I have on this matter, I came to the understanding that I need to upgrade my first ec2 instance - `mongodb`(3.0.9) to be compatible with the `mongo db` I need to copy to i.e 3.6.8.

I have followed the set of instructions in the `mongo` docs [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) to gradually update to 3.2 and then 3.4 etc.. but I although I completed all instructions, my mongo db version remains 3.0.9

Im assuming that it is related to the `bitnami` infrastructure and the way they have there `mongodb` installed, but I cannot point to the problem.

I am really stuck on this matter. (perhaps I don't need to upgrade `mongo` db and there is a workaround etc.. because I am banging my head in the wall)

T.I.A

Comment: With SQL databases you'd do an export from the old database to a common format, then an import. Is that possible with MongoDB?

Comment: Use mongodump and mongorestore?

Answer (score 1):

The conventional way is to dump the data from old mongodb instance (`mongodump`), then upgrade it's installation to a newer version, then import the data back from a logical dump (`mongorestore`).

Take a look at the [official documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/backup-and-restore-tools/) about what tool should be used on each stage.